# Is there a WWDC 2019 session videos summary?

Tags: ios, swift, session, conference, wwdc

There are so many videos released each year and it would take way too much time to actually watch them all. Many times you don't even know that it was interesting for you before you actually got to know the details.

Therefore my question: Is there a protocol of the most important facts (not the transcription, that's just everything) released by Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a GitHub repo with notes to many many sessions:

https://github.com/Blackjacx/WWDC

Just skim through the bullet points and decide yourself if it's worth watching the video. Hope the repo helps some of you and maybe it gets a WWDC tradition.

#### Contribution Note

Contribution is highly welcome, since actually it makes A LOT of work to watch all the videos. So if you watch one that is not already covered, feel free to open up a PR and add your notes. As a bonus you get mentioned on this 1000++ star repo.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you much. This is exactly what I was looking for!!